# Are there any disadvantages to not using blade and having the front totally decoupled from the back end in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I was at an interview yesterday and the interviewer asked me a few questions about blade and I replied saying that I don't use blade and only use Laravel to build RESTful web services which I then consume using a front end technology such as Angular.

He insisted that blade was very useful and there a few disadvantages to not using blade. I couldn't understand what he was talking about. And neither do I clearly remember any points he made.

I am curious to know are there any disadvantages to not using blade in Laravel?

Comment: Well if you make the decision to build an application that uses Angular and a REST backend I don't see any use for Blade. But that's not a decision whether you want to use Blade or not, but a much bigger architectural design question.
For "normal" applications Blade is certainly useful. However its not *that* powerful. The only thing it basically does is convert code like `{{ $foo }}` into `<?php echo $foo; ?>`. The engine just replaces some strings, not much more logic behind it. It would be interesting though, what points this guy made...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there are a few advantages of AngularJS over blade and vice versa:

Advantages blade:

- Laravel has some html helpers and form helpers.
- Laravel adds a token to a form for preventing csrf!
- When you open a form you can give a route to it. The method and the action are defined by blade based on the given route.
- With blade you can create macro's and view composers.
- When validating a form you can return back with the input and the errors which is quite easy.
- Blade is not realy slow because laravel cache the compiled views.
- With blade you can extend and include views which is more DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself)
- On paginator objects you can call `->links()` which is very easy for pagination although this is also nice to do with AngularJS.
- Blade can automatically escape you're data with `{{{$var}}}`.
- If you've to write a multi language application blade and laravel comes with easy methods to do achieve this.

This are in my opinion the advantages of blade. Look at the [blade docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates) for more information and figure out what you like!

Comment: The CSRF point did come to mind. But is there a way to accomplish that while not using blade?

Comment: Yes that's really possible. Yust do it like laravel does it. Laravel creates a hidden input with a token. Verify the token each time the form is submitted. You can read more about csrf and how to prevent at the owasp website: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet